# Custom highlighting style on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am new to Google spreadsheet and I'm wondering if there are any other ways to draw attention to a box rather than just change its colour.

I want to emphasize a box drawing a circle on it.

I saw that you can draw a figure and assign it to a script, Is it possible to make it transparent and through a script be positioned over a box with a certain value? Or this feature is meant only to trigger scripts?

Comment: The _assign to a script_ option is meant to trigger a script when clicking on the figure.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create a draw through a function?

Comment: There's no script API to create a drawing. If you really, REALLY want a circle, you might perhaps be able to tweak a [pie chart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/pie-chart-builder) into doing what you want. However, I get a feeling that you are not looking for the right tools here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use Google Apps Script to insert an image to a sheet in a spreadsheet, but as far as I know, Google Apps Script doesn't have a service to draw that image, so you should create or get the image first.

If you are new to Google Spreadsheet and to Google Apps Script, consider to start learning about them at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

UPDATE:

The Slides Service was added to Google Apps Script, so now it's possible to make a drawing there, but it's not yet ready to edit a box to draw a circle into it directly on Google Sheets, but it's closer :)

See [Extending Google Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/).

**Related Q&A on Stack Overflow**

- [Modifying a drawing using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8996422/1595451)

Comment: OK, is not what I hoped for but I don't mind few more lines of code.